Is the notion of 'spin' for massless fields poorly worded or am I confused?
My question is coming from the (perhaps not fully correct?) understanding that the different spins amount to different possible irreducible representations of SU(2): spin 0 being a singlet (acting on a 1 dimensional space), spin 1/2 a doublet (acting on a 2 dimensional space) etc. In this view, a spin 2 particle should be given realised by an irreducible representation where the space is 5 dimensional.
Now, if I understand correctly, this would be the case, if the particle had positive mass (eg from Wigner's classification https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner%27s_classification)- that is, a spin 2 particle with positive mass would be realised by a 5 dimensional field. The notion of spin so far is arising from the fact that the 'stabiliser group' is $SU(2)$ for this massive case. Is this correct so far?
Now, the graviton would be massless. From Wigner's classification, the stabiliser group is now no longer $SU(2)$, but we still call it spin 2, even though it does not seem to relate to $SU(2)$ and it also does not mean that the corresponding particle should be a 5 dimensional field (for example this was discussed in this question What is the relation between the metric tensor and the graviton?).
So now to return to my titled question: based on what I wrote above, is the notion of spin for massless fields slightly misguiding (ie when we say "gravitons are would-be spin 2 particles" is it a little untrue, at least if spin is to be taken as labelling $SU(2)$ representations) or am I simply confused?

WP.

The stabilizer group is $U(1)$, representations of which are all one-dimensional and labelled by a half-integer $h$, called helicity (its actually ISO(2) but that's a whole other story). CPT invariance requires that representations $h$ and $-h$ must always come in pairs. Thus, massless particles always have TWO polarizations no matter what their $h$ is. In several texts, $h$ is often called spin, though it should really always be referred to as helicity.

Thank you, that is more or less what I was trying to imply in my question above- does this mean you agree that it is perhaps poorly named, and would be better to say the graviton is a "helicity 2" particle rather than spin? In any case, I was struggling to reconcile these thoughts with the nice answer below by MathZilla, which seems to put massive and massless spin 2 representations under the same umbrella, seemingly justifying the use of naming "spin 2" for either case. Do you have any thoughts on that, given your comment?

Prahar is exactly correct. It should be called helicity or chirality, not spin. Unless it was spin-0, in which case there is no pair of helicity, just 1-dimensional. But by now, the convention is somewhat fixed.

@sillyQsman - ya, it should be called helicity for clarity. But, what's happened has happened. I think its not that big a deal. The term "spin" doesn't just refer to the group SU(2) anyway, so it really doesn't matter.

I personally like to think of massive and massless representations as entirely separate entities. Their groups are completely different (SU(2) vs. ISO(2)). That being said, the idea of separating massive polarizations into longitudinal and transverse is quite useful for many reasons so I don't think @MathZilla's answer is incorrect either.

Firstly, the graviton is absolutely a spin-2 particle and not a 5-dimensional field (as the post you linked asked about). We do not need to discuss SU(2), we can just stick with good-ole spin-2 representation of SO(3).
The spin-2 representation of SO(3) can be written as $U(R) = R_i^aR_j^b$ which is a product of two rotation matrices (i.e. each copy acts on a vector). The corresponding spin-2 state can be written as
\begin{equation}
\Psi(x)^{ij} = \langle\mathbf{x}|\psi\rangle^{ij} =\sum_\lambda\Psi_\lambda(\mathbf{x},t)\epsilon^{ij}_\lambda 
\end{equation}
where $\epsilon_\lambda^{ij}$ is the polarization tensor with helicity $\lambda$. They too transform under a product of rotation matrices. There is a short procedure in order to derive the polarization matrices that can be readily found online, but you will find that there are 5 matrices, $\lambda = \{\pm 2,\pm1 ,0\}$.
Now, to get to a 4-dimensional tensor representation of spin-2, we can promote the 3-dimensional matrices to a 4-dimensional one by placing $0$s in the new row and column since the time-components are non-dynamical. At the moment, we have 5-dynamical degrees of freedome. We can perform a Lorentz boost on all of the matrices of the form
\begin{equation}
\epsilon^{\mu\nu}\rightarrow \Lambda^\mu_\alpha\Lambda^\nu_\beta\epsilon^{\alpha\beta}
\end{equation}
which for the spin-2 matrices gives
\begin{equation}
\epsilon_{\pm 2}^{\mu\nu}\rightarrow \frac{1}{2}
\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&0&0\\
0&1&\pm i&0\\
0&\pm i&-1&0\\
0&0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
which is actually unchanged from their previously un-boosted matrix. Note that they are orthogonal $\epsilon^{ij}_{\pm 2}p_j = 0$. However, the $\pm 1$ and $0$ matrices change and pick up factors of $\propto p_z/m$ and $\propto E/m$ (for a boost in the z-direction).
Now, obviously in the massless limit the spin-2 modes are completely fine, but the $\pm 1$ and $0$ modes are not. In order to remove these modes we must project them out via $\epsilon^{ij}p_j = 0$.
To give a TLDR version: massive spin-2 particles carry 5 polarizations while massless spin-2 particles carry only 2 polarizations.
Now, the much more modern take on massless fields is to solely consider transformations under Wigner's little group and consider what is a particle, not a field (which is why I tried to never say field above). The beginning of section 2 of Scattering Amplitudes For All Masses and Spins gives a really great introduction and derivation of how particles are representations of Wigner's little group.
